# Tumbleweed Questions Section

Tags: feature-request

I would like to propose a tab called tumbleweeds or cause a full on revolt.  Either is suitable

I frequent the tsql tag and am always a bit miffed to see in the unanswered section questions from July 9th 2013.  I assume there are other questions below, but it generally keeps the unanswered section pretty stale, boring, and almost nauseaiting to return to the unanswered section.

Consider this:
[Unanswered TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsql?sort=unanswered&pageSize=50)

Seems July 9th 2013 if one of the talented TSQL frequents hasn't got to it, chances are its probably not going to be answered.  Nor should it be first.

Answer (score 3):

Unanswered section is going away: [New navigation for Stack Overflow is in alpha testing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256814/new-navigation-for-stack-overflow-is-in-alpha-testing). Long live "need answer" tab with its own sorting features...

Meanwhile,  you can [achieve similar effect with search parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Btsql%5D%20isanswered%3A0%20hasaccepted%3A0%20closed%3A0): `[tsql] isanswered:0 hasaccepted:0 closed:0` is pretty close to "unanswered", especially if you throw in `score:0..` to also remove questions with a negative score. The search results can be sorted in various ways, and the desired sort can be bookmarked.